# Ultraweakly closed left ideals of von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, weak-convergence, von-neumann-algebras

The following is a proposition of Takesaki's Operator Theory:
[image]
[image]

My questions are:

1- He claims for two sided ideal $\cal m$, $e \in M\cap M'$. While I think for $\sigma -$ weakly closed two sided ideal we can conclude it. Also I think he uses of $\sigma-$ weakly closed ideal in the proof. Am I right?

2- He claims if $M$ is a factor, then every nonzero two-sided ideal is $\sigma-$weakly dense in it. I think in this situation, there is just a nonzero $\sigma-$ weak closed two sided ideal because the central projections are $1, -1$ and ${\cal m}_1=M(1) = M(-1) ={\cal m}_2$,  but there may be different two sided ideals with equal $\sigma- $ weak clusers. If this is true, I would like to see an emample about it.

$\sigma- $weak means ultraweak topology.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

niki, he keeps the assumption that that $\mathfrak{m}$ is $\sigma$-weakly closed. So the third line should read:

> *If, in addition, $\mathfrak{m}$ is a two-sided ideal, then...*.

Of course, when you deal with norm-closed ideals it is very easy to come up with a counter-example: take the compact operators inside $B(H)$. This is also an illustration to your second question: compact operators are $\sigma$-weakly dense in $B(H)$ and $B(H)$ is a factor.

$II_1$-factors are algebraically simple: they have no non-zero proper ideals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how can I show that if $M$ is a factor, then it contains a $\sigma-$ weakly dense proper ideal ?

Comment: This is not true. What is true is that if there is a proper two-sided ideal, then it is $\sigma$-weakly dense.

Comment: Dear Tomek Kania: Thanks so much

Comment: You are very welcome :)